# Parse Push not displaying on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

We are using Parse Push Plugin https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin with custom parse server. Push messages are coming to the device into GCMService but not rendering. The ParsePushBroadcastReceiver not sure if its being invoked. I don't see any errors in logs.

Also on debugging i see that GCM Receive Intent's are getting called, and not 
com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE , not sure if its default behaviour.

I have the following in AndroidManifest.xml , Also i am using parse android version com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1

```
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="github.taivo.parsepushplugin.ParsePushPluginReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
      <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
      <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Any help would be of greatly appreciated

Comment: currently opensource parse server has no bultin push mechanism, you need to use thirdparty integration like OneSignal on server side, you sure server side push function is working ?

Comment: Yeah we are using OneSignalPush Adapter

Comment: I can see message is coming from Onesignal  and i can see message status as Delivered and i can see the message being received on the Device as well, in the GCMService class of parse, 

But it is not coming in String dataString = intent.getStringExtra("data");
 
When i evaluate intent.getExtras().toString(), i can see the whole message along with message id etc. Also the intent.getAction is coming as com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE 

Any clue what might be missing?

Comment: what is output of (.toString ? ), attach the output to the question!

Comment: This is the output Bundle[{google.sent_time=1485622180837, custom={"a":{"sound":"default"},"i":"64547e02-a01a-48d6-8550-7d7812e7402c"}, from=1021248970841, alert=Test Massage, google.message_id=0:1485622180843863%f1b059b4f9fd7ecd, parseWakeLockId=0, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]